# Adjektiv mit bestimmtem Artikel im Genitiv

Tags: genitive, adjective-ending

> Wie heißt der Autor, dessen "neues" Buch du so gut fandest?

Warum ist es neues nicht neuen? Danke im Voraus.

Answer (score 1):

Zwar steht das Relativpronomen *dessen* im Genitiv. *Neues Buch* steht hingegen im Akkusativ, wobei [*neues*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:neu) hier stark dekliniert ist. Warum das so ist, erkennt man vielleicht besser, wenn es nicht als Frage formuliert ist:

> - Du fandest (irgend)ein *neues Buch* so gut.
> - Du fandest sein *neues Buch* so gut.
> - Du fandest dessen *neues Buch* so gut.

Und in einer Frage eingebaut:

> - Wie heißt der Autor, dessen *neues Buch* du so gut fandest?

In all diesen Fällen ist *neues Buch* im Akkusativ.

Comment: Also, ist dessen/deren ein unbestimmter Artikel?

Comment: Nein, es ist ein Relativpronomen.

Comment: Aber ich meine, funktionert es wie ein unbestimmter Artikel? Das verwirrt mich ein bisschen und ich muss das gründlich verstehen, um das weiter zu benutzen, wenn ich spreche.